# In ColdFusion how can I match a posted password to an SHA256 encrypted password in my table?

Tags: coldfusion, sha256

I am creating a log in form using ColdFusion, but I cannot figure out the syntax to check the password in my table which is encrypted using SHA256. I have researched this and so far only found complicated answers, mostly unrelated to what I need.

Here is the code I have for my query:

```
   <cfquery name="qVerify" datasource="MyDSN">
SELECT  *
   FROM cryptuser
   WHERE firstname = '#firstname#'
   AND   password = '#password#'
</cfquery>
```

So a password entered and posted via form needs to be matched to a password encrypted in my table, does anyone know if this is possible?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you would just need to encrypt the password entered by the user and then use that variable in your query.

```
<cfset EncryptedPassword = Encrypt(form.password,'your key','SHA-256')>

<cfquery name="qVerify" datasource="MyDSN">
SELECT  *
FROM cryptuser
WHERE firstname = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#firstname#">
AND   password = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#EncryptedPassword#">
</cfquery>
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your code, it makes sense to encrypt the password so the encryptions instead are being checked for a match, I tried it and it didn't work though, I received this error:


The SHA-256 algorithm is not supported by the Security Provider you have chosen.

Any ideas what this means?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I just checked the version to see if it was this and I am on version 9 enterprise, is this the reason why it is not supported?

Thanks.

Comment: SHA is not supported by the Encrypt() function in CF, but you shouldn't use Encrypt() for passwords anyway since it is "two-way", ie you can Encrypt() and Decrypt(). If your server were hacked, all the passwords could be decrypted using "your key". Instead use the one-way Hash() as David Faber advises. You should also "salt" your password hashes - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7669374/coldfusion-salting-my-hash

Comment: Matt, sorry to resurrect an old post, but ... that is just wrong :-) Might want to add a notation at the top about "hash" to avoid confusing the next guy that comes across it.

Comment: (... and hopefully that came across in the light-hearted vein I intended :)

Answer (score 5):

To encrypt with SHA-256 you don't use the encrypt() function but rather the hash() function (SHA is a one-way hash):

```
<cfset EncryptedPassword = Hash(form.password, "SHA-256") />
```

I believe CF will return an all-uppercase hash so make sure you compare to the uppercase of the password encrypted in the database:

```
AND UPPER(password) = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" value="#EncryptedPassword#" />
```

Also watch for encoding! It's possible that the data in the database could have a different encoding than the default (e.g., iso-8859-1 rather than utf-8).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hash() in CF does return an upper case string, but if you're also using CF to hash the passwords when they're created then there's no need to use UPPER() when comparing. Won't do any harm though.

Comment: Right, I was just thinking in the event they were created using DB functions, or by PHP, etc.